# Creating pandas dataframe from accessing specific keys of nested dictionary

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

How can below dictionary converted to expected dataframe like below?

```
{
    "getArticleAttributesResponse": {
        "attributes": [{
            "articleId": {
                "id": "2345",
                "locale": "en_US"
            },
            "keyValuePairs": [{
                "key": "tags",
                "value": "[{\"displayName\": \"Nice\", \"englishName\": \"Pradeep\", \"refKey\": \"Key2\"}, {\"displayName\": \"Family Sharing\", \"englishName\": \"Sarvendra\", \"refKey\": \"Key1\", \"meta\": {\"customerDisplayable\": [false]}}}]"
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

Expected dataframe:

```
    id           displayName              englistname          refKey
    2345            Nice                   Pradeep             Key2
    2345         Family Sharing            Sarvendra           Key1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d['getDDResponse']['attributes']).explode('keyValuePairs')
df2 = pd.concat([df1[col].apply(pd.Series) for col in df1],1).assign(value = lambda x :x.value.apply(eval)).explode('value')
df = pd.concat([df2[col].apply(pd.Series) for col in df2],1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
      0     0     display englishName reference   source
0  1234  tags  Unarchived  Unarchived    friend  monster
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nk03 ...Sorry i had not posted complete input dictionary and expected output dataframe earlier. Now edited the both. Please suggest how can we do...Please Please help as i am blocked.

Comment: I had edited my original post...the dictionary and expected daataframe